# Errors when pip install psycopg2 to virtualenv

Tags: pip, virtualenv, psycopg2

I have created virtual environment

```
leo@kodar:/var/www/python$ mkvirtualenv -p /var/www/python/3.5.0/bin/python3 --no-site-packages env350_185
```

and trying to install psycopg2 to it.

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

This gives me a big log with errors. Here is the resume string of output log:

```
Command /var/www/.virtualenvs/env350_185/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xibdmand/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-gtvfmn3f-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/.virtualenvs/env350_185/include/site/python3.5 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xibdmand/psycopg2
```

When I try to do the same with virtual environment created with system version of Python3

```
 mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 --no-site-packages env_sys
```

it gives success.

What could the problem be? Other packages like Django 1.8.5 can be installed correctly. I have also tested it with python 3.4.3 from custom folder and get the same error. Only system python3 (3.4.3) works.

Full pip error log is here: https://gist.github.com/leoKiddy/25beaa96c67b2cfa2263